# Call Fetch with Click

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have setup a fetch request that request a random phrase from an API. This is called when the window reloads or load initially. I created a button that when clicked would re-run the fetch I have setup. Currently it is not working and I am getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'fetch' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.

Javascript Code

```js
var generateBtn = document.getElementById('generateSP');
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', fetch);

fetch('https://random-words-api.herokuapp.com/w?n=10')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('w3review').value = data;
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your code with a function. You can't call fetch like this.

```
var generateBtn = document.getElementById('generateSP');
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchData);

function fetchData() {
  fetch('https://random-words-api.herokuapp.com/w?n=10')
    .then(function (response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(
          'Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status
        );
        return;
      }
      response.json().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('w3review').value = data;
      });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind the click handler directly to `fetch`, that simply won't work. Create your own function that calls `fetch()` and bind the listener to that

```js
const loader = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://random-words-api.herokuapp.com/w?n=10')
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${await response.text()}`)
    }
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('w3review').value = data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

document.getElementById('generateSP').addEventListener('click', loader);

loader() // initial run
```

---

To elaborate on the error message, `fetch` **must** be called bound to the `window` object. Any event listener is bound to the element triggering the event so it would be like trying to call

```js
const boundFetch = window.fetch.bind(generateBtn)
boundFetch(event)
```

which results in your error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the fetch call in a custom callback, it cannot be used as an argument to addEventListener:

```js
var generateBtn = document.getElementById('generateSP');
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', myFetcher);

function myFetcher() {
fetch('https://random-words-api.herokuapp.com/w?n=10')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById('w3review').value = data;
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  })
}
myFetcher();
```

Your original code calls fetch() on click with no url or arguments passed into it.